# Не могу добавить 2ой аргумент в php

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят есть некий `php` файл который парсит данные с БД `Mysql` и дает в `Json` формате .
Есть кирилица в базе данных и `Json` дает место кирилицы

> ???

знаки ,дописал в `php  mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` все ок теперь лишь цифры которые надо сделать `uncode` ,к строке print`(json_encode($data));` добавяю `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`  но тогда в браузере пишет

> Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long

Помогите разобраться точна такая же функция работает на моем wamp servere и никаких проблем .

Comment: какая версия php? JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE работает в версиях php 5.4+

Comment: у меня всия 5.3

Comment: есь какието альтернативы*?

Comment: кроме как обновления серва ?

Comment: json_encode($data,256) - попробуйте вот так

Comment: я уже это пробовал не сработало

Comment: тоесть врнинг ушел но не расшифровалось все также цифры

Comment: у вас таблицы в бд с какой кодировкой?

Comment: utf 8 general ci

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50083/discussion-between-b-denis-and-elik).